# Determine info about file being accessed on Windows File server

Tags: file-management, tracking

TL:DR - Is there a way to get detailed access logging beyond what user accessed it and when? Windows Audit isn't detailed enough.

Explanation: 
I'm working with a client trying to reverse engineer the setup due to a sudden knowledge loss. There is a file that stores sensitive information on this Windows File Server. Audit events in the Event Viewer indicate that the Administrator account is accessing it every half hour. Beyond obviously being against best practices and needing to be reconfigured, I've been trying to find out what this file is being used for. Process ID leads back to System, it's 0x4. No scheduled tasks. Any ideas?

Could SQL Server Reporting services look that way? We need to determine the way to secure this file.

Comment: Why don't you block/rename this file and see what breaks?